# Is it possible to get all rows from a table and apply conditions using php?

Tags: php, mysqli

**For example:**

```
// GET ALL ROWS
$get_rows = $sql->query("SELECT expire,date_original,date, FROM table");
$gr = $get_rows->fetch_rows;
```

Then work with the results...

```
$expired = count($gr->expire == 0);
$active = count($gr->expire == 1);
$reposted = count($gr->date_original != date);
```

Or something to that effect?

Comment: `count`? Will always return 1 in your case.

Comment: The code above is hypothetical and only to an attempt to illustrate what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this isn't really a good idea, especially if you have more than a million records.

And in order to perform the count(), you need to go through each record and understand the information. If you have a few rows, this doesn't matter, but when the records get large, you are better off, issuing the correct count sql.

You are better off writing a SQL like this:

```
select SUM(IF(expire == 1, 1, 0)) as expired, 
SUM(IF(expire == 0, 1, 0)) as notExpired 
from table;
```

You can still apply conditions, but if you have enough resources to handle the amount of records you are retrieving, then use the above solution, but when you are talking about large enterprise amount of data, S

Comment: @Churk You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9437579/edit) your answer to add aditional information rather than commenting on your own answer.

Comment: `SUM(IF(expire = 1, 1, 0)) as expired` [w/o syntax error above] worked perfect. Thank you _Churk_ and everyone else who responded.

Comment: I think you edit, cuts off 1/2 of the original commend. But the main point is still there.

Answer (score 1):

use [`mysqli_fetch_object`](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_object) :

```
  $result = mysqli_query("SELECT expire,date_original,date, FROM table");
    while ($gr= mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        $expired = count($gr->expire == 0);
        $active = count($gr->expire == 1);
        $reposted = count($gr->date_original != date);
    }
```

Comment: A mysql function when OP is about mysqli? That's not an answer at all.

Comment: i use this all the time, it works great. also it get results from TEXT and BLOB fields (in case you got one)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the SQL `COUNT` function

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `expired` from `table` WHERE <your_condition>
```

Comment: As long as it uses the columns he is looking for instead of * this should work.

Comment: I have around 50 conditions I need to apply to the results. I already have everything working but am trying to avoid so many calls to mysql.